# How do I make button refresh page in WKWebview

Tags: swift, xcode

I want the button to be "tappable" so that it refreshes the WKWebview

```
    let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 40)
      let button = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
      webView.scrollView.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    var originalURL: URL!

    var count = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let script = generateCountButtonScript() {
            contentController.addUserScript(script)
        }

        if let script = generateAddCSSScript() {
            contentController.addUserScript(script)
        }

        contentController.add(self, name: "count")

        config.userContentController = contentController
        setupWebView(config: config, url:"https://app.salonized.com/franchise/reports/overview")
    }

    func generateCountButtonScript() -> WKUserScript? {
        guard let scriptPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js"),
            let scriptSource = try? String(contentsOfFile: scriptPath) else {
                return nil
        }

        let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

        return script
    }

    func generateAddCSSScript() -> WKUserScript? {
        guard let cssPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "style", ofType: "css"),
            let cssString = try? String(contentsOfFile: cssPath).components(separatedBy: .newlines).joined() else {
                return nil
        }



        let source = """
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)';
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        """

        let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        return script
    }

    func setupWebView(config: WKWebViewConfiguration, url: String) {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        view.addSubview(webView)

        let layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            self.originalURL = url
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

            let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
            toolbarItems = [refresh]
            navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

            //button
            let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 40)
            let button = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            webView.scrollView.addSubview(button)

            let buttonFrame2 = CGRect(x: 120, y: 50, width: 50, height: 40)
            let button2 = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame2)
            button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction2), for: .touchUpInside)
            webView.scrollView.addSubview(button2)


        }// in that way button will be scroling with webView.
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        if let url = webView.url {
            webView.reload()
        } else {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL))
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonAction2(sender: UIButton!) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL))
    }

}



extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "count", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
            count += 1
            let javascript = "document.getElementById(\"countLabel\").innerHTML = \"Count: \(count)\";"
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for helping! I get 2 errors: error 1: Use of local variable 'buttonAction' before its declaration - error 2:@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes

Comment: that's because you need to move this whole `@objc func buttonAction` method outside of your current method where you're declaring `button` variable.

Comment: @MitchellLooijer this might give you a clearer idea. answer edit

Comment: Now I get this error : 'override' can only be specified on class members and: Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'buttonAction(sender:)'

Comment: aren't you using any class? plz share all your code of this file.

Comment: Maybe not, im still a beginner sorry. it says my code is too large to paste. is there a way to send it to you? Thanks again for all of this!

Comment: drive or dropbox, share link here

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j7q0ji2p0g1r5m/ViewController.swift?dl=0

Comment: It would even be nicer that if the button is pressed that the user go's to a specific page but I don't know if that is possible in this code

Comment: @MitchellLooijer answer edited, this is your whole code with fixation.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're the king!

Comment: @Mitchell Looijer, glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! Is it also possible to have the same button next to it but with only the function : webView.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL)) ?

Comment: another button left or right of the existing button?

Comment: Right preferably

Comment: Answer updated, check a new button in red is introduced right of the previous black button.

Comment: Thanks a million. Learning a lot now. Sincerely thank you sir!